# Determine the next heading level for dynamic content using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page that loads dynamic content. I need to load additional content in and need to know what heading tag I need to use. So for example, the initial load may contain an `<h2>` tag in which case I will need to use an `h3` tag as the heading of the additional content.

Is there a way to find out what heading I should use?

Trying this but returns nothing, event though the page has an `h1` tag:

```
$myElement.closest( "h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6" );
```

Comment: possibly, but pls put some code in ur post, with an attemp if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest` will not work because in the DOM hierarchy, `h1`, `h2`, ... are not generally used to create a nested level of element nodes (except for some formatting). More concretely, an `h2` element is generally not a child of a `h1` element, but a sibling of it.

The following will select all parents, and all their preceding siblings, and filter those for `hX` elements. As jQuery will sort the resulting set of elements in document order, the last of those `hX` is the one to be taken:

```
$h = $myElement.parents().prevAll().addBack().filter('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').last();
```

Comment: That won't work as there are no heading siblings in some cases. I guess I can check to see if there are heading siblings using your suggestion, if none are found then I could try `parents().prevAll(...)`?

Comment: I updated my answer. It also needs `addBack()` to add the parents themselves again, and then the final selections is not with `first()` anymore, but with `last()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Determine the next heading level

You can use [header-selector](https://api.jquery.com/header-selector/) using [nextAll](https://api.jquery.com/nextall) and grabbing with [first](https://api.jquery.com/first) element like this:

```
$myElement.nextAll(:header).first(); //finds next header element to the $myElement header
```